# Is the second "to" needed here? "I am going to listen and (to) read"

Tags: american-english, infinitives, parallelism, conjunction-reduction

Which one is correct? Can I use both?

"I am going to listen and read."
"I am going to listen and to read."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It really depends on how you group the *to* and what you intend it to mean.

If you are using the phrasal verb "going to" as in:

> What are you going to do when you get there?
>   I am [going to] listen and read.

But if you are just using the verb "go" as in:

> Why are you going to the exhibition?
>   I am going [to listen] and [to read].

Comment: 'But I have decided to stay and enjoy myself', with an obviously simplex verb, doesn't need a repeat to-particle. This is not necessarily an incorrect claim, but needs supporting evidence to be considered a high quality ELU answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Yes. I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how distinct you want *listen* and *read* to sound. Tying both objects to one infinitive conveys the sense of a single activity, while preceding each object with *to* conveys distinct activities.